# Validate Simple XML against 2 XSD - XMLCopyEditor

Tags: xml, ubuntu, xsd

I'm self learning about XML. I can  validate XML with 1 XSD but when I try to validate a XML with 2 XSD failed. I had been reading about namespaces to identify the "specific tags" but when I put the "any operator" doesn't work.

The validator **xmlcopyeditor**(Ubuntu) Said: "no declaration found for element **children**"

Here a XML :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persons xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.microsoft.com any_part1.xsd http://www.gumball.com any_part2.xsd">
      <person>
        <firstname>Hege</firstname>
        <lastname>Refsnes</lastname>
        <children>
          <childname>Cecilie</childname>
        </children>
      </person>
      <person>
        <firstname>Stale</firstname>
        <lastname>Refsnes</lastname>
      </person>
    </persons>
```

First XSD:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                               targetNamespace="http://www.microsoft.com"
                               xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"                          elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="persons">
         <xs:complexType>  
         <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="person">
                         <xs:complexType>
                                  <xs:sequence>
                                       <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
                                       <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
                                       <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
                                  </xs:sequence>
                        </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element> 
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:schema>
```

Second Xsd:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://www.gumball.com"
    xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="children">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="childname" type="xs:string"
          maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    </xs:schema>
```

W3school - AnyOperator:
http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp

Answer (score 0):

The first issue is then element children declared in schema 2 is defined in the namespace http://www.gumball.com. When you use it in your XML file you are using the default namespace (http://www.microsoft.com). See the xmlns:gb attribute and then the gb: prefixes for children and childname.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Created with Liquid XML 2015 Designer Edition (Trial) 13.1.0.5909 (http://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
<persons xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:gb="http://www.gumball.com"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.microsoft.com any_part1.xsd http://www.gumball.com any_part2.xsd">
    <person>
        <firstname>Hege</firstname>
        <lastname>Refsnes</lastname>
        <gb:children>
            <gb:childname>Cecilie</gb:childname>
        </gb:children>
    </person>
</persons>
```

Your second issue is that you can only have 1 person object. I've turned on the explicit cardinality indicators so you can see this more clearly.
[image: Explicitly showing cardinality using Liquid XML Studio]

Comment: thanks. Is there any way to work without putting the prefix GB (with 2 or more XSD).

If you look at the example of w3 " Myfamily.xml " (http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_any.asp ) does not put the prefix gb. Is a mistake?

Comment: Its because the Persons is in the microsoft namespace and children is in the gumball namespace. You can do somrthing lilke

<children xmlns="http://www.gumball.com">
            <childname>Cecilie</childname>
</children>